# image + audio = mp4: how to make video smaller?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to add a JPG to an MP4 to make an MP4.

As there is only one image to make the video I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce the video size?

Command:

```
$ ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Results:

- `image.jpg` = 26.7K (image not so clear)
- `audio.mp3` = 64.6M (54 minutes)
- `output.mp4` = 80.6M (video result is not so clear, music still good)

Is it a reasonable size for MP4?

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to meta mp4 so that it plays mp3 only and keep screen fixed on one jpg to save size :)

Comment: What is the target player, device, or site for the output?

Comment: I m trying to upload the .mp4 to Youtube.com

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## For uploading to YouTube

### H.264: smallest files

This method uses libx264 to encode H.264 video. It is slower than the stream copy method below, but potentially will output a smaller file size.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image.jpg -i music.mp3 \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 0 -c:a copy -shortest output.mkv
```

### Stream copy: fastest process

This method just [stream copies](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (no encoding) the image into the MKV container. It's super fast, but if size is important than the method above may produce a smaller file.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image.jpg -i music.mp3 -c copy -shortest output.mkv
```

- YouTube accepts just about anything so these commands use a few tricks to make encoding faster, or make the file size small, and to keep quality high because YouTube will re-encode whatever you give it. Your player probably won't like it but YouTube will.
- In these examples a very low frame rate is used which should process faster than the default of 25 fps.

---

## Widest compatibility for any player

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i music.mp3 -vf "scale='min(1280,iw)':-2,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 -preset medium -profile:v main -c:a aac -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- This should play on just about anything except very ancient devices (change `-profile:v main` to `-profile:v baseline` if that is the case).
- If your audio input is already AAC then change `-c:a aac` to `-c:a copy` to avoid unnecessary re-encoding.
- Encoding time will be longer and file size will be bigger than the YouTube commands above.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

Comment: Could you provide a line of code to make a.jpg + a.mp3 = a.mp4 in 1280 * 720 with lowest frames/sec allowed by youtube ? Also as there is only one job, do i need to delete "-loop 1" ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SIDU The existing command does what you request (other than outputting MKV instead of MP4), but I don't know the lowest frame rate supported by YouTube is. You'll just have to experiment. Why do you require MP4 when you are just uploading to YouTube?

Comment: I tried it but it says: `Unrecognized option 'preset'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: @NineCattoRules Hard to say without more info. Use a pastebin site to show your full `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output from the command, then provide the link in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled FFMPEG using mc3man repository and now works well!

Answer (score 4):

With only the information you provided this what I can think of.

Let's go by pieces:

> As there is only one image added to the video. I m wondering if there is a way to reduce the video size eg force bit rate/second = 1 instead of 28 ?
>
> As it is a still image, no need to change. just stay still.

What you're talking about there it's [frames per second (fps)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) not bitrate. And you're right in the concept. Beign just one still image 1 fps wouldn't be a problem.

> Is it a reasonable size for mp4? Does image size matter a lot?

In this case image size wouldn't have a significant weight because we are dealing with just one still picture. If it were a high quality video then it's a different issue.

> Should I resize jpg to 1080 * 720, and make additional settings in ffmpeg to output as 720p (what is the ffmpeg setting then :) ?

The resolution you are saying it's 1280x720.

I dont' see the point in the `-loop 1` option here, it will only slow down the process. Did you use `-shortest` cause the file has more than 1 input stream? If no then there's no reason to use it. Since you used `-acodec copy` I will have to assume that you don't want to re-encode it.

For an output of 720p 1fps without re-encoding and not touching bitrate:

`ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -c:a copy -s 1280x720 output.mp4`

Beign the case that it has more than one input stream and you want ffmpeg to finish encoding at the shortest stream then:

`ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -c:a copy -s 1280x720 -shortest output.mp4`

Now if you have to change the bitrate (let's say 1024k as an example);

`ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -c:a copy -b:v 1024k -bufsize 1024k -s 1280x720 output.mp4`

See: [Limit the output bitrate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Limiting%20the%20output%20bitrate)

> **-c:a copy** = Copy the input audio stream so we not re-encode.
>
> **-b:v** = The bitrate specified to be (not precisely) constant.
>
> **-bufsize** = It's the interval in which calculates the average bitrate. Meaning the lowest more loss quality image but more accurate
>   bitrates according to the specified in *-b:v*.
>
> **-s** = The actual size of the video output.
>
> **-framerate** = The input frame rate we want that the output will use.

Note that if you still want a smaller size video at one point you will have to sacrifice quality in order to achieve that. And other ways to do it involve re-encoding with lossy compression.

From what you say, the information you provide and what you are trying to do I think it seems that your target is to embed album-art to mp3. If that's your goal this would fit your requirements better:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 output.mp3`

> **-map_metadata** = The ffmpeg metadata specifier to output file from infile. In this case (*zero*) the global metadata.
>
> **-map 0** = Input stream 1 (audio).
>
> **-map 1** = Input stream 2 (image).

If nothing here suits your requests please give more information.

Comment: Consider using `-framerate` as an input option and removing the output `-r`: otherwise the default input framerate of 25 will be used and then `ffmpeg` will drop frames to achieve `-r 1`. If you just declare the input frame rate then the output will use the same frame rate.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that. Edited to reflect the changes suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. My origianl ffmpeg line of code was a copy-paste from google search, which I have no idea what is what.