# Combine an image and audio file to create a Video in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: video, 18.04, ffmpeg, youtube

I am trying to create a video file(can be any format) from an image file(also any format) and a mp3 audio file.
I found that we can use `ffmpeg` and tried the answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg):

The following produces a video

```
ffmpeg -i ep1.png -i ep1.wav ep1.flv
```

But the video is not right, the video player crashes and the video cannot be uploaded to youtube because youtube also cannot process it.

The following gives an error:

```
ffmpeg -i still.png -i narrate.wav -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 final.flv
```

The error being

```
Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc'
```

I tried all other methods in answers to [that](https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg) question each giving a different error.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in XOrg mode.

I have [these](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riyafa/Riyafa-Abdul-Hameed--web-page/gh-pages/others/log.txt) `ffmpeg` encoders.

How can I achieve this in Ubuntu 18.04?

Note: **This is in Ubuntu 18.04. Other answers as in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868283/ffmpeg-mp3-jpg-mp4-howto-make-video-smaller/868831#868831) are not working and I am not trying to compress the video. I only need to be able to create a video**

Comment: When I try that I am getting this error: Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'libvo_aacenc'

Comment: Duplicate of [ffmpeg mp3 + jpg = mp4](https://askubuntu.com/a/868831/59378).

Comment: I am saying these are not working in Ubuntu 18.04. It  is not a duplicate

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what goes wrong in the2 answers already provided.

Comment: Without seeing your new command that is "not working", and the resulting error, we can't provide any suggestions.